# Async Sleep in .net 2.0

Tags: c#, multithreading, sleep, wait

I have a question. I couldn't find anything related to this on Google that's why I hope you experts on SOF can help me out.

Basically I am trying to perform a Sleep, but these are the conditions.

- This Sleep which I like to get shouldn't interrupt the program (freeze it)
- It should be .net 2.0 based - Can't use `Task.Delay()` in this case.

I basically have a `Form fade in` and `fade out` and in between I like to wait a few seconds before executing the `fadeout`. On the form are also `animations` etc so I need to make sure they won't hang when sleeping.

Does someone have an idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Definitely use a [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as suggested by Servy.  Otherwise you'll invariably end up with some kind of tight loop containing a small call to Sleep() and DoEvents(), and that's usually **never a good thing**.

Comment: @Idle_Mind: Note that Servy didn't explicitly suggest the `Timer` class from the Winforms namespace. In fact, his wording implies using literally the same `Timer` class that the `Task.Delay()` method uses (`System.Threading.Timer`), i.e. one that allows a one-shot timer. I agree with your suggestion to use the Winforms `Timer` class, as it will be easier to use in the Winforms environment (no `Invoke()` required). But it does mean you have to remember to disable the timer as soon as it fires the first time, to get the one-short behavior.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, True, true.  I wonder how the original `fade in` and `fade out` portions were implemented in the first place.  I would use the Timer for the whole process and simply change the `Interval` for the longer pause in between.

Comment: @Idle_Mind: agreed. Unfortunately, the details aren't here. But you're right...it's likely the OP is just adjusting the `Opacity` value, and using a `Timer` to do that already. They should just integrate the whole operation into a single timer-based, key-frame animation on the `Opacity` property. Or, switch to WPF where this kind of functionality is built-in. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a `Timer`.  It's how `Task.Delay` is implemented under the hood.  Just configure the timer to only fire once, and set its interval for the length of your delay.